# QT : render in release differs from debug

Tags: qt, qml, material-design

I'm having a strange issue with a C++ and QML app which render differently whereas i'm in debug or release : 
[image]

The debug (left) render is the correct one.
In release (right) the accent colors is wrong and all the fonts are bigger. It's also seems to miss some shadows.
Both builds are done with visual 2015 after complete clean of the solution.

This how my window is set :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QMainWindow * parent) :QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DontCreateNativeWidgetSiblings);
    mQuickWidget = nullptr;
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);

    this->setMinimumSize(640, 480);

    mQuickWidget = new QQuickWidget(this);

    QQuickStyle::setStyle("Material");

    setCentralWidget(mQuickWidget);
    this->setWindowTitle("Générateur de licence");

    qmlRegisterType<mycompany::Licensor>("com.mycompany.licensor", 1, 0, "Licensor");

    mQuickWidget->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    mQuickWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
    mQuickWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop);

    mQuickWidget->show();
}
```

And this part of the QML :

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Controls14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.1
import com.prynel.licensor 1.0

Item {
    Material.theme: Material.Light
    Material.accent: Material.DeepPurple
    id: base
    width : 900
    height: 500

    function twoDigit(n)
    {
       return n > 9 ? ""+n : "0"+n;
    }

    Licensor {
        id: licensor
    }

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("1. Licence")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("2. Presets")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("3. Options")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("4. Finalisation")
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        width: parent.width
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.top: bar.bottom
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        //LICENCE
        Item {
            id: licenceTab
            Label {
                id: labelacti
                text: qsTr("Code d'activation :")
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 15
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 35
            }

            TextField {
                id: input_codeacti
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 230
                anchors.verticalCenter: labelacti.verticalCenter
                width: 201
                antialiasing: true
                placeholderText: qsTr("Code d'activation")
                onTextChanged: {rect_result.visible = false;}
            }


        }

        // Lot of other fields

    }

    Controls14.Calendar {
        property var linkedItem
        id: calendar
        parent: base
        visible: false
        anchors.verticalCenter: base.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: base.horizontalCenter

        onClicked:
        {
            linkedItem.text = base.twoDigit(date.getDate()) + "/" + base.twoDigit((date.getMonth() + 1)) + "/" + base.twoDigit(date.getFullYear());
            calendar.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not putting everything as there is lot of field which should not be the source of the problems.

What can cause this different result in the UI ?

Comment: the right one looks like a Material style while the left style not. which one is Debug?

Comment: debug is left , release right

Comment: I would be willing to be it's the Controls 1 imports that are somehow messing things up. Try removing them (and their types, like Calendar) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe are you providing a Qt Quick Controls special configuration file [qtquickcontrols2.conf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-configuration.html) ?

The configuration file is usually embedded into the application's resources, but it can also be located in the directory specified by the environment variable QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_CONF. There are some [more environment variables](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-environment.html) that can affect styles. Look to your QtCreator's project settings and check the environment differences between the Debug and the Release run settings.

Comment: I was not provinding any qtquickcontrol2.conf. So i tried to add one and that solve the problem. Istill dont really kwnow why it's not working if i dont add this file to my qrc but at least it's fixed :)